# Is my salary halal given that it's paid from an account which mixes money earned from a bar?

Tags: halal-haram, money

I'm working in a golf club as a security supervisor. There is a bar in the golf club, but I'm not at all involved.

However, the golf club makes money from landscape, the bar and from golfing.  At the end of month they mix this all money together, and give the salary to the employers.

Is my salary is halal?

Comment: Better you can search job somewhere(by working there) to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 7):

From where you are getting salary is not a matter, for what you are getting salary is to be considered for halal/haram.

> Allah has cursed wine and has cursed the one who produces it, the one
>   for whom it is produced, the one who drinks it, the one who serves it,
>   the one who carries it, the one for whom it is carried, the one who
>   sells it, **the one who earns from the sale of it**, the one who buys it,
>   and the one for whom it is bought- **Tirmidhi**

From the above mentioned hadith, if your security supervising also includes the bar area then surely, it's haram (sad to say). If not(ie, you have no contact with the bar), it would be safe. In the hadith,it clearly says that `one who earns from the sale of wine`, so if you have no part in selling the wine it won't be a problem. Mixing of money won't affect that. You are getting salary for the security supervising of golf only.

As I already mentioned, it is better to search for job somewhere to avoid confusion.

Allah knows the best.

Comment: @DavidWallace, reference added

Comment: @DavidWallace, added some clarifications.